# WiFi Tethering not working when using security

Tags: security, tethering

I have a rooted Galaxy SII (not branded, from Germany) running CyanogenMod 10.

I can't connect to my tethering network when I'm using security (WPA / WPA2-PSK). With an open network, it works just fine, but obviously, that's not what I'd prefer.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to fix this?

Comment: Might I ask why this was edited? The greetings I can understand, but why did you remove two tags?

Comment: I'm not the one that do the edit but device tags should only be used for device-specific issues. As for rooting tag, your question is not specifically about rooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems tethering on SGS2 on CM10 is currently broken, according to [Entropy512 on xda developer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1782350&page=4):

> CM10 supports tethering, however WPA/WPA2 tethering was broken on devices with bcmdhd wifi until I fixed it earlier this week. Some devices may not have the fix enabled yet (It has to be enabled on a per-device basis, since the "fix" will break devices that don't need it.)

Comment: So, is this going to be fixed in the next version? Or what does he mean by "fixing it"?

Comment: no idea, you'll have to ask Entropy512 for that